# Java null pointer exception on recursive binary tree method

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

this method is giving me a null pointer exception and I don't know why that is. Is there something wrong with the recursion code?

```
 public void clearAllSelections(){
    //Recursively clear all the selections in the sub-tree of this node
    //basis:
    isSelected = false;
    if(isLeaf()) return;

    //recursion:
    childrenRight.clearAllSelections();
    childrenLeft.clearAllSelections();

}
```

Comment: childrenRight or childrenLeft is null. use your debugger to identifiy why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `isLeaf()` check is not sufficient, since a node in a binary tree may have a single child, so you must add null checks :

```
public void clearAllSelections(){
    //Recursively clear all the selections in the sub-tree of this node
    //basis:
    isSelected = false;
    if(isLeaf()) return;

    //recursion:
    if (childrenRight != null)
        childrenRight.clearAllSelections();
    if (childrenLeft != null)
        childrenLeft.clearAllSelections();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

do a null check on childrenRight and childrenLeft before making the function call